# Logging in to Google Apps and Gmail at the same time?

Tags: gmail, login, google-workspace

How is possible to login to both Gmail and to Google Apps. I activated `Multiple sign-in` to both accounts, still I am not able to switch them.

Answer (score 2):

**Hmm.. I can sign in to Google Apps and Gmail at the same time:**

[image]

I don't think I did anything special:

1. Enable multiple domains on all accounts
2. Sign in to Gmail (`www.gmail.com`)
3. Sign in to my domain (`www.google.com/a/leftium.com`)
4. Navigate to "inbox" for domain email OR Gmail account.

*I think I noticed the ability to sign in to Gmail and  Google Apps simultaneously with the new interface.*

Answer (score 1):

Multiple sign-in is probably not available in Google Apps yet. If you use Google Chrome you can have an install of Chrome and an install of Chromium or Chrome Canary and have them sync; passwords will sync, bookmarks will sync, etc... but active logins do not, so you could have Chromium set up to use the Google Apps account.

An upcoming feature in Chrome may be having different windows with different profiles. I believe that this is available with some amount of instability by enabling a flag in either Chrome Dev or Chrome Canary, but it didn't work for me (button didn't work). This may become a feature you could use in future, though.

Many browsers also support profiles, however I don't think any of them can have two instances of on browser open at the same time with different profiles (OS limitations) on Mac and Windows.